# return false even though data is present in the array

Tags: reactjs

I make a query that responds with users' data.

This user is obtained from api response.

```
users = [
       {
        "email": "test123@gmail.com",
        "name": "test user",
        "uid": "1612848114665355196015101548881161"
    },
    {
        "email": "test123@gmail.com",
        "name": "test user",
        "uid": "1612848114665355196015101548881161"
    }
]
```

I need to find if a user (test123@gmail.com) exists in the array, and if not create a user.

I looped through each of the arrays checking for the user exists, if yes return true or else false.

But Even though the user exists in the array, it gives false.

**Code:**

```
  const checkIfUserThere = async () => {
    let newUser = "test123@gmail.com";
    await users.map((user: any) => {
      if (user.email === newUser) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const userExists = await checkIfUserThere();
      console.log(userExists);
      if(userExists === false){
         createuserapi("....") //create user api is called
      }

    })();
  }, [users]);
```

Above returns **false**

Comment: Why you can't use `find`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***It will work as you want***

```
 const checkIfUserThere = () => {
   let newUser = "test123@gmail.com";
    for (const data of users) {
     if (data.email === newUser) {
       return true;
        }
    }

     return false;
  };
```